# Customize Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two components called **one.component.html** and **two.components.html**. I tried to customize Angular material datepicker for only one component and leave another component to have Angular Stock datepicker. If I write a custom css code in **one.component.css**, it doesn't work. So, I have to write in **Style.css**. But writing in the **Style.css** will customize both the components. How do I specify customization in different component?

Comment: Add filtering selector in what you have done in styles.css. eg `.custom` and add that class to component you want to custom.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/theming-your-components.md

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### shadow-piercing descendant combinator (deprecated)

You can use [`::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) in the CSS definition of the respective component to force your style down through the child component tree into all the child component views, e.g.:

```css
/* two.component.css */
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected){
  border-color:darkblue;
}
```

### Custom CSS classes

Alternatively, you can assign different CSS classes for each DatePicker, which you then style using style.css. The @angular/material/datepicker [API](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) provides two inputs on mat-datepicker for that purpose:

> **panelClass** Classes to be passed to the date picker panel. Supports the same syntax as ngClass 
>   **dateClass** Function that can be used to add custom CSS classes to dates

Using this, your OneComponent template could now look like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker panelClass="datepickerOne"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

and the corresponding styling in style.css like this:

```css
.datepickerOne .mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected){
  border-color: darkgreen;
}
```

If you opt for the custom CSS class solution, I'd suggest you create a second CSS file within your component folder with only your datepicker custom styles and import that one into your `style.css` to keep everything organized.

I've created a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-styling-datepicker)** for you to check out the mentioned possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

Better architecture would be creating a `datepicker.scss` file in `assets/scss` folder with your custom SCSS. And the importing inside the components you wish have the custom-styling of datepicker.
    `@import "src/assets/scss/datepicker.scss";`
This way you can add complexity to your designs in an easy-implementation.

Comment: Isn't this actually the same with using the component's css file which @Chris stated it did not work. Defining the rules inside the component's css file or importing from scss is not enough in this case because it only affects the component's template unless you use ng-deep shadow piercing combinator.

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage ng-deep selector. It has been deprecated for a long time but not replaced with anything by CSS workgroup yet. Many developers are still using it since alternative ways have their own drawbacks too.

Inside your component's css file you can have something like this:

```
  ::ng-deep yourcomponent{
    //custom css
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Still Use this

```
::ng-deep mycomponent{
    //custom css
}
```